# Logout from NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user?

Tags: windows, user

I was trying to troubleshoot one of our client's computer and restart it.
For some reason, it logged in automatically to **nt authority\system** and i'm not sure how to log it out and come back to its regular user. I tried doing a system restore and it didnt help.
Any way to bring it back?

Thanks.

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j75H.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

All Windows allows Ctrl-Alt-Del and then select logout.

Then Login as the user you want.

You can also restart from this screen if need be.